# How to build a HashMap<String, Set<String>> using java8 collectors

Tags: java-8, collectors

I am trying to learn java8 and specifically collectors for building collections. I have a pre-java8 way for building a particular HashMap<String, Set> . It is the following:

```
HashMap<String, Set<String>> setHashMap = new HashMap<>();
Set<String> set = Sets.newHashSet("1000", "1001");
setHashMap.put("Id01",set);
```

I am trying unsuccessfully to build the same structure with java8 as follows:

```
String[] IDS = {"1000", "1001"};
Sets.newHashSet("Id01", Arrays.stream(IDS).collect(toMap()));
```

However, this does not even compile. I would be grateful for any insights. Thanks

Comment: In one case you add into map a set as a value for the key "Id01", in the second case you try to add into set a String and a Map. BTW, toMap() needs mapping functions.

Comment: So you expect `Sets.newHashSet(…)` to produce a `Map` and `toMap()` to produce a `Set`? If there’s a `Sets.newHashSet(…)` in your codebase isn’t there also a `Maps.newHashMap(…)` so you can simply use `HashMap<String, Set<String>> setHashMap = Maps.newHashMap("Id01", Sets.newHashSet("1000", "1001"));`?

Comment: @Holger thanks for the response. I was looking for a solution that uses collectors (as my post says).

Comment: There’s no sense in using a Stream operation for processing a tiny amount of static data whose result is actually given at compile time. But if you want to bring in Stream operations at all costs, you may probably use `Map<String, Set<String>> setMap = Stream.of("1000", "1001") .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> "Id01", Collectors.toSet()));`

Comment: @Holger thanks for this. As inefficient as it is, this is a useful learning exercise for me. In fact, I both learn how to do what I wanted to do, as well as learn its inefficient and see that I should not do it this way for tiny amounts of static data. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mr Shaikh provided me with a nice solution, but it required Java9, and I wanted a solution using Java8. Mr Holger gave me a Java8 solution. That is what I am posting here as a solution. However, he pointed out to me that this is not an ideal solution for tiny amounts of static data (which is what my use case is). However, as I mentioned in my original post, this was a learning exercise for me to use Java 8 with collectors. So the below solution satisfies my original intent (even though not particularly efficient for my use case):

```
Map<String, Set<String>> setMap = Stream.of("1000", "1001") .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> "Id01", Collectors.toSet()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need to stream your array and  collect to Set, since you need a `Map<String, Set<String>>` the following snippet should help

```
String[] IDS = {"1000", "1001"};
Map<String, Set<String>> hm = Map.of("Id01", Arrays.stream(IDS).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
```

P.S. - Your code is trying to create a set of a string and map which wouldn't work

Comment: thanks for this, but it is requiring me to use java9 rather than java8? because of the Map.of